# Check which ViewController made a segue (from the destination ViewController)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a code that gives random segues to my 12 ViewControllers.

In ViewController1 it looks like this;

```
let segues = ["1-2", "1-3", "1-4", "1-5", "1-6", "1-7", "1-8", "1-9", "1-10", "1-11", "1-12"]
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(segues.count)))
        let segueName = segues[index]
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segueName, sender: self)
```

And in ViewController 2 it looks the same, but the segue names change to;

```
let segues = ["2-1", "2-3", "2-4", "2-5", "2-6", "2-7", "2-8", "2-9", "2-10", "2-11", "2-12"]
```

(The `"1"` changes into a `"2"`) - and so forth for all 12 ViewControllers.

.

Now, what I want to do is delete the ViewControllers that has already been shown, so that the next segue won't go back to any of the previous ViewControllers.

Example:

• ViewController1 makes a segue to ViewController2 (`"1-2"`)

• ViewController2 deletes the segue `"2-1"` from the array `segues`

• ViewController2 then makes a segue to ViewController3 `"1-3"`

• ViewController3 deletes the segue `"3-1"` and `"3-2"`

and so on...

Comment: So you just want to pick out a random segue-identifier from the segues-array, but not having any of the repeat until you've showed them all?

Comment: @T.BenjaminLarsen Exactly! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

1. Keep an array of the viewControllers you have visited as a property in each of your viewControllers.  Let's call this `visited`.  Also, create a *protocol* called `TracksVisited` that all of your viewControllers will adopt:

   ```
   protocol TracksVisited {
       var visited: [Int] { get set }
   }

   class ViewController1: UIViewController, TracksVisited {
       var visited = [Int]()

       ...
   }

   class ViewController2: UIViewController, TracksVisited {
       var visited = [Int]()

       ...
   }
   ```
2. Add the current viewController number to this list:

   ```
   let vc = 3  // current viewController
   visited.append(vc)
   ```
3. Generate the list of `segues` and choose one:

   ```
   // generate list of all viewControllers
   let all = Array(1...12)

   // remove visited from all
   let rest = all.filter { !visited.contains($0) }

   // create list of segues
   let segues = rest.map { "\(vc)-\($0)" }

   // choose random segue and go there
   let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(segues.count)))
   let segueName = segues[index]
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segueName, sender: self)
   ```
4. In `prepareForSegue`, pass the list of `visited` to the destination viewController:

   ```
   if let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? TracksVisited {
       destinationViewController.visited = visited
   }
   ```

Comment: There is no `destinationViewController` ? How do I know which one is the destination if they are randomly chosen? :-)

Comment: I updated the answer for how to send the visited array on to each viewController.

Comment: Btw, how could you make this without using the names of my segues and without me changing them? Can I delete all the segues I did before? This is crazy?! :)

Comment: You can get rid of `let segues = ["1-2", "1-3", "1-4", "1-5", "1-6", "1-7", "1-8", "1-9", "1-10", "1-11", "1-12"]` from your original code, but don't get rid of the actual segues that you wired up in the Storyboard!

Comment: Ok thanks! Is it possible for me to delete ViewController10 as long as I get rid of the segues in the storyboard? Do I have to change the code?

Comment: You want to get rid of 10, but you'll still have an 11 and 12?

Comment: Could I then just instead of `let all = Array(1...12)` just type in all values except `10` ? :-)

Comment: Yes exactly, get rid of 10 but keep 11 and 12! :)

Comment: var all = Array(1...9) + [11, 12]

Comment: Here's another way:  `var all = Array(1...12).filter {$0 != 10}`, or you *could* just pretend 10 has already been visited: `visited.append(10)`.  If you declare `visited` as `var visited = [10]` then no one will ever go there.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect that your main-logic could be made into something a lot more manageable but with the current setup I'd suggest having a separate `SegueCoordinator` to deliver the next segue until it runs out (2-11, 11-3, 3-6, 6-4...) etc:

```
import GameplayKit

class SegueCoordinator {
    private var numberOfViewControllers = 0
    private var segues = [String]()

    init(numberOfViewControllers: Int) {
        self.numberOfViewControllers = numberOfViewControllers
        setupSegues()
    }

    func nextSegue() -> String? {
        let segue = segues.first
        segues.removeFirst()
        return segue
    }

    private func setupSegues() {
        let allIds = Array(1...numberOfViewControllers)
        var shuffleIds = GKRandomSource().arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(allIds) as! [Int]
        while shuffleIds.count > 1 {
            let availableIds = shuffleIds.filter{$0 != shuffleIds.first!}
            let segue = "\(shuffleIds.first!)-\(availableIds.first!)"
            segues.append(segue)
            shuffleIds.removeFirst()
        }
    }
}
```

Then you'll create the coordinator from whateverViewController you'd like to start: `let coordinator = SegueCoordinator(numberOfViewControllers: 12)` (this could easily be changed to pick a random firstControler from the coordinator itself).

Then just ask the coordinator for the nextSegue:

```
let segue = coordinator.nextSegue()
```

Pass the coordinator on to the nextVC in prepareForSegue.

Comment: How do I put this code in use? Do I keep the `let segues` array with my strings? How and when do I use your `let segue = coordinator.nextSegue()` ?

Comment: No, you don't need the array of strings anymore. Each viewController needs to have a `segueCoordinator` property and you pass it along in the prepareForSegue `destinationViewController.segueCoordinator = segueCoordinator` when it is time to move to a new viewController you just request the nextSegue and use the string as the segueIdentifier. `performSegueWithIdentifier(segue, sender: self)`

Comment: How do I pass it to the " `destinationViewController` " when its random and I don't know which one it is? :-)